# Seagate Cheetah Size

Tags: raid, scsi, dell-poweredge, seagate

I just got some replacement drives for a server here, went to pop one in, and it turns out that the 72Gig for a Seagate is slightly below the 72gig of the Maxtors that we currently have.

Does anyone know if there is anything hidden on the drive causing this discrepancy? I'm facing a rebuild of the array if I can't find an extra 150MB on this disk. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't help you now, but in the past I've taken to leaving around 500~700Mb leeway at the end RAID sets, where we haven't been able to procure enough spares of the same model and the HBA won't accept drives of a larger size.

It's less of an issue nowadays - we only tend to run into it when using the max configurations in blades.

Answer (score 4):

No.  You're buggered.  Either:

1. Get a disk of the same model as the one you have, formatted the same (sometimes OEM disks can have a slightly different format to ones with generic firmware)
2. Get a 146GB disk and be prepared to waste half of the capacity.
3. Get a disk with the array manufacturer's firmware, which will be set up so it can act as a drop in replacement.

Comment: great answer (unfortunately). if i could choose two answers i would. the leaving some space at the end of the array won me tho.

Answer (score 1):

You really can't do anything.

Even if you could claim unused sectors to do this, it would be a very bad idea. Unused sectors are used to replace failed sectors so using them right away would strongly increase the risk of data loss and decrease the life of your hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

The others are correct, nothing you can do (except rebuild or get larger disks)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's anything you can do sorry.